# Build failed in JBPM

Tags: jbpm

I have added a script task in a workflow and added dependency in pom.xml like below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuZdF.png)

And Maven dependency is added .

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Builid is failing with error:

> [KBase: defaultKieBase]: Process Compilation error Syntax error on
>   token "import", throw expected org.json.JSONArray cannot be resolved
>   to

But the build is failing. Could you please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbmqZ.png)

## script task code:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONArray objects = new JSONArray(Result);
        JSONArray finalArray = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = objects.getJSONObject(i);
            if (jsonObject.getString("ac_id").equals(acc_id)) {
                finalArray.put(jsonObject);
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: and please print the code into your script task

Comment: Hi Bashir, i have added the build error. Could you please tell what do you mean by print the code into script task

Comment: the problem is in your code of the script task, please post it too

Comment: what is `Result` variable? is it a global variable of your process? and I guess it is a String value, no?

Comment: yes its a global process variable and i am storing the result REST task(which is above of this script task) and processing that Result in script task and is String datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in script task we never import classes, each time you call a class you have to type its complete path. this is applied not only for libraries, even if you create your own class (called Data Object in jBPM) you have to specifie its full package path. Even if you want to declare a String value you have to put   `java.lang.String name;`

So here, you have to specify the path of `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` each time you use it. So you have to replace your code to

```
java.lang.String resTmp = (java.lang.String) kcontext.getVariable("Result");
org.json.JSONArray objects = new org.json.JSONArray(resTmp);
org.json.JSONArray finalArray = new org.json.JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < objects.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = objects.getJSONObject(i);
    if (jsonObject.getString("ac_id").equals(acc_id)) {
        finalArray.put(jsonObject);
    }
}
```

use `kcontext.getVariable()` to get the actual value of the variable in the task, and each time you call a variable you have to cast it into its requested data type.

Comment: If I want my custom class to be imported, do I need to upload the package in modeler? I'm facing the same issue with custom class and tried giving complete path but it didn't work for me. Can you suggest on this please

Comment: you have to upload the class and add it to the dependencies of the current Jbpm project. now you can call it without problems